# How in pandas/python to generate this last in first out row logic in Dispatch column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 3 commodity. For example I received 60 orders for cake. I need to dispatch/ship the earliest batch first. Took a look at "BUN" commodity. I need script to generate this dispatch column. The logic here is that the sum of dispatch column for each commodity should not exceed the order received.
I have attached the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for unicom in dfRaw["commodity"].dropna().unique(): 
    df1=dfRaw[dfRaw["commodity"] == unicom].reset_index(drop=True)
    batches = df1["qty_purchased"].to_numpy()
    cum_batches = batches.cumsum()
    inter = np.minimum( cum_batches, df1['qty_sold'].iloc[0] )
    df1["Test"]=np.diff( inter, prepend = 0 )
    df = df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution as I don't know pandas well enough.

To do this it's best to work with cumulative values for both orders and batches.  Then take the minimum of the batch and order cumulatives for each intersection between the two arrays.

Below is a numpy script, perhaps it will help inspire a pandas one.

```
import numpy as np

orders = np.array( [10, 20, 15, 25] ) 
cum_orders = orders.cumsum() 

batches = np.array( [ 20, 20, 20, 20 ] )                               
cum_batches = batches.cumsum()

temp = np.minimum( cum_batches[:, None], cum_orders[ None, : ] )

cum_orders, temp                                                         
# Orders: array([10, 30, 45, 70]),   # cum_batches

# temp:  array([[10, 20, 20, 20],    # [ 20,
#               [10, 30, 40, 40],    #   40,
#               [10, 30, 45, 60],    #   60,
#               [10, 30, 45, 70]]))  #   80 ]

inter = np.diff( temp, prepend = 0, axis = 1 )  # Decum across columns.

np.diff( inter, prepend = 0, axis = 0 )  # Decum down the rows.

# orders [10, 20, 15, 25]    # Batches

# array([[10, 10,  0,  0],   #  [ 20,
#        [ 0, 10, 10,  0],   #    20,
#        [ 0,  0,  5, 15],   #    20,
#        [ 0,  0,  0, 10]])  #    20 ]
```

To get LIFO (Last In First Out) the batches need to be with the newest batches before the older ones in the array.  Can the equivalent be arranged in pandas?

For the 'bun' example data, simplified if there is only one order.

```
batches = np.array( [ 15, 5, 25, 10, 5 ] )                             
cum_batches = batches.cumsum()                                         

inter = np.minimum( cum_batches, 50 )
inter                                       
# array([15, 20, 45, 50, 50])

np.diff( inter, prepend = 0 )                  
# array([15,  5, 25,  5,  0])
```

Assuming two orders [ 30, 20 ]

```
orders = np.array( [ 30, 20 ] )
cum_orders = orders.cumsum()

batches = np.array( [ 15, 5, 25, 10, 5 ] )                             
cum_batches = batches.cumsum()

temp = np.minimum( cum_batches[:, None], cum_orders[ None, : ] )
#                       batches to rows, orders to columns

inter = np.diff( temp, prepend = 0, axis = 1 )  # Decum across columns.

np.diff( inter, prepend = 0, axis = 0 )  # Decum down the rows.

# array([[15,  0],
#        [ 5,  0],
#        [10, 15],
#        [ 0,  5],
#        [ 0,  0]])
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I tried to replicate this option. But it does seem to work. I am fine to use numpy not restricting to any particular module. Can you replicate this model for the item "Bun" in my example. And the final output should be the "Dispatch" column.

Comment: @sumanth1601 I've added two versions.  One assuming there can only be one order, which is simpler.  The second assumes two orders summing to 50 (30, 20).

Comment: Thank you Chris, your logic worked perfectly. I was able to get what was required. Awesome :) Below is my script, let me know if its fine.

Comment: dfRaw=pd.read_excel("lifo1.xlsx")
dfRaw.columns = dfRaw.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')

df = pd.DataFrame()

for unicom in dfRaw["commodity"].dropna().unique():
    df1=dfRaw[dfRaw["commodity"] == unicom].reset_index(drop=True)
    batches = df1["qty_purchased"].to_numpy()
    cum_batches = batches.cumsum()
    inter = np.minimum( cum_batches, df1['qty_sold'].iloc[0] )
    df1["Test"]=np.diff( inter, prepend = 0 )
    df = df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
print(df.head(15))

Comment: It looks OK to me but I've not used pandas enough to confirm.  Does it give the correct results with your data?  It's best to add the code to your question or create an answer to your own question as code is very difficult to read in a comment as the formatting is completely lost.  In general FIFO and LIFO are best handled using cumulatives then taking differences for period or batch specific values.